Estimating Margin of Error with low population sizes
I help run a small regular event which subsequently surveys a selection of trade attendees in order to gauge their experience and try and improve it for future events. The response rate has so far been around 40%, out of a population that is not expected to ever be more than 100, and currently is around 50. Some of my questions have possible answers of 'Poor'/'Average'/'Good', and the proportions of these can obviously be tracked event-on-event.
Given that there are confounding factors that are likely to make the responding population materially different from the overall population, is it possible to judge numerically whether the change in answer ratios over time is significant? I can assume that the responses are representative to a degree, but the standard MoE calculator using Z values seems to assume an infinite population or at least a population that is magnitudes larger than the sample size, which is not the case here.
At the moment I have a weighted score which looks like this:
((A x 1)+(B x 0.5)+(C x -1))/n where:
A = 'Good' responses
B = 'Average' responses
C = 'Poor' responses
n = Total responses
This gives me an overall score between -1 and 1 which can be tracked over time. Is there a way of calculating or estimating a Margin of Error for this score? Or do I just eyeball it? Do my sample numbers render the collection of this data pointless in any event?
Many thanks.
